# Cannot find module error for a node js app running in a docker environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, containers, dockerfile

This application is written in ES6 and compile to ES5 using babel. The build files stored in the following order inside the build folder. the dockerfile reside in the outside the build folder.

```js
-build
---public
---server
---shared
---package.json
-Dockerfile
```

This is my docker file.

```js
FROM node:8.9-alpine
ENV     NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD    ./build/  /usr/src/app

RUN npm install --production --silent

RUN ls /usr/src/app/
RUN ls /usr/src/app/server/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD  ["node", "/usr/src/app/server/index.js", "--config", "/usr/src/app/config.json"]
```

This is the output I get when running the image build command.

```js
Sending build context to Docker daemon  16.08MB
Step 1/9 : FROM node:8.9-alpine
 ---> 406f227b21f5
Step 2/9 : ENV     NODE_ENV production
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 090d3e742281
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fa2a344bd8ee
Step 4/9 : ADD    ./build/  /usr/src/app
 ---> 93559e34a45a
Step 5/9 : RUN npm install --production --silent
 ---> Running in ebc2b6b2ba1a
added 212 packages in 15.212s
Removing intermediate container ebc2b6b2ba1a
 ---> b49180988a07
Step 6/9 : RUN ls /usr/src/app/
 ---> Running in b140530cb8ca
build-info.json
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
public
server
shared
Removing intermediate container b140530cb8ca
 ---> 0712e1b84e1a
Step 7/9 : RUN ls /usr/src/app/server/
 ---> Running in b6570fbc8d2c
auth
configuration
database
files
index.js
sessions
users
utils
Removing intermediate container b6570fbc8d2c
 ---> c49775551756
Step 8/9 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in 9318dfc0f183
Removing intermediate container 9318dfc0f183
 ---> ad20aec92973
Step 9/9 : CMD  ["node", "/usr/src/app/server/index.js", "--config", "/usr/src/app/config.json"]
 ---> Running in fa6c2e388906
Removing intermediate container fa6c2e388906
 ---> ba1ced3be150
Successfully built ba1ced3be150
Successfully tagged tiqri:myclaim
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

After image created, i start the image using the following command.
"docker run -d -v C:\portal\environments\development:/usr/src/app/ -p 3000:80 f057e4bc8191"
There is volume map for config files.

But the container, not running. when I check the logs, it shows the following error.

```js
C:\portal>docker logs c819d39fea61
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/server/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I couldn't figure out why giving this error even though all folders are in place in the docker container(RUN ls- shows the folder structure in the container).
still, I couldn't start the container because of this error.

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer given by @Marcos Casagrande, made changes to the docker file and container run command as follows. Now I'm getting a new error.

After made changes in the Dockerfile.

```js
FROM node:8.9-alpine
ENV     NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD    ./build/  /usr/src/app
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/environments
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/environments/development

RUN ls /usr/src/app/
RUN ls /usr/src/app/server/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD  ["node", "/usr/src/app/server/index.js", "--config", "/usr/src/app/environments/development/config.json"]
```

container run command changed as follows,
"docker run -d -v C:\portal\environments\development:/usr/src/app/environments/development -p 3000:80 ca290d67ff34"

Then I get the following error when checking the logs. The container does not start yet.

```js
/usr/src/app/environments/development/config.json
/usr/src/app/environments/development/config.json
fs.js:646
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/environments/development/config.json'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at loadJSON (/usr/src/node_modules/convict/lib/convict.js:364:25)
    at /usr/src/node_modules/convict/lib/convict.js:501:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.loadFile (/usr/src/node_modules/convict/lib/convict.js:500:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/server/configuration/configuration.js:156:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
```

Comment: Show the contents of: `C:\portal\environments\development`, does that folder has a `server` dir in it?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande that folder contains the config files required to run the app. the server folder contains in the build folder which I mention in the beginning.

Comment: Then see my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the contents of `C:\portal\environments\development` I will assume that there isn't `server/index.js` in it.

> I couldn't figure out why giving this error even though all folders
>   are in place in the docker container(RUN ls- shows the folder
>   structure in the container). still i couldnt start the container
>   because of this error.

`RUN ls` is executed after you copy the build dir, when building the docker image, if you run `ls` when you start the container you will see that there is no `server/index.js`

While you're copying the `build` folder to `/usr/src/app/`, you're overriding that files when mounting `development` folder on `/usr/src/app`.

The easiest way, is to mount `C:\portal\environments\development` on `/usr/src/app/development`.

```
docker run -d -v C:\portal\environments\development:/usr/src/app/development/ -p 3000:80 f057e4bc8191
```

Also you can mount `development` on `/usr/src/app` and then use the `build/server` that was build on the image:

```
-v C:\portal\environments\development:/usr/src/app/ -v /usr/src/app/server
```

You will have to do that for every folder that you need from the built image.

```
-v /usr/src/app/server -v /usr/src/app/public -v ...
```

Comment: Please check the updated question. I followed what you mention in here. I overcome the issue I mention at first but got another one.

Comment: enter the container, and run `ls` on `development` and show the output

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem running a docker container. I figured out I might I have created the image wrongly and I resolved this by deleting the image and rebuilding. but first I had to delete the existing containers of the image like below

```
    docker rm containerId
```

then I deleted the image like below

```
    docker rmi imageId
```

then I rebuilt the image and ran to create a new container.